# Edit an xml file using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have an xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2008">
  <my id="1">Hi this is one</my>
  <my id="2">Hi this is one</my>
  <my id="6">Hi this is one</my> 
  <my id="7">Hi this is one</my>
   <my id="8">Hi this is one</my>
   <my id="9">Hi this is one</my>
</myTable>
```

i want to append (1)  to first 'my id="1"'.So that my resultant xml will be as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2008">
  <my id="1">Hi this is one(1)</my>
  <my id="2">Hi this is one</my>
  <my id="6">Hi this is one</my> 
  <my id="7">Hi this is one</my>
   <my id="8">Hi this is one</my>
   <my id="9">Hi this is one</my>
 </myTable>
```

i want this thing to be done in python regular expression

Thanks

Comment: why the hell do you want to use regex ??? parsing xml is sooo easiest with elementtree :)

Comment: Regular expressions cannot properly parse XML.  An XML parser like elementtree is the way to go.

Comment: use an XML parser...using regular expressions for parsing markup is bullshit...how often must that be recommended? ten times a day?

Comment: There was some errors when i tried to parse using an xml parser like elementtree.The error was like unsupported xml to parse.So i went for regular expression.This is not the real xml file.So you can't reproduce the error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'(<my id="1">.*)(</my>)')

with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(newfile, 'w+') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        match = r.search(line)
        if match:
            f.write(match.group(1) + '(1)' + match.group(2))
        else:
            f.write(line)
```

what you want?

This searches for lines with a given pattern and, if they match, take their content and plug something in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok to create a new file? If so, then:

```
import re

f = open(newfile, 'w+')

for line in open(your_file, 'r');
  match = re.search(r'id="1"', line)
  if match:
    f.write('<my id="1">Hi this is one(1)</my>')
  else:
    f.write(line)

f.close()
```

Comment: Hi friend Thank you for your valuable quick reply

How can i write to a file using regular expression if i want to append (1) to all xmls where <my id="1">

Thanks